# Error: Type [somePage] in [somePath] is part of the declarations of 2 modules

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, build

I'm going crazy with this error with ionic 3 that I get when I try to build a --prod Android version of my app.

### Error:

```
Running app-scripts build: --prod --iscordovaserve --externalIpRequired --nobrowser

[21:21:54]  build prod started ... 
[21:21:54]  clean started ... 
[21:21:54]  clean finished in 2 ms 
[21:21:54]  copy started ... 
[21:21:54]  ngc started ... 
[WARN] Error occurred during command execution from a CLI plugin
       (@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova). Your plugins may be out of date.
Error: Type TestPage in
/Users/sergidb/Desktop/Borrar/myStackApp/src/pages/test/test.ts is part of the
declarations of 2 modules: AppModule in 
/Users/sergidb/Desktop/Borrar/myStackApp/src/app/app.module.ts
and TestPageModule in 
/Users/sergidb/Desktop/Borrar/myStackApp/src/pages/test/test.module.ts! 
Please consider moving TestPage in 
/Users/sergidb/Desktop/Borrar/myStackApp/src/pages/test/test.ts 
to a higher module that imports AppModule in 
/Users/sergidb/Desktop/Borrar/myStackApp/src/app/app.module.ts 
and TestPageModule in 
/Users/sergidb/Desktop/Borrar/myStackApp/src/pages/test/test.module.ts. 
You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes TestPage in 
/Users/sergidb/Desktop/Borrar/myStackApp/src/pages/test/test.ts then import 
that NgModule in AppModule in 
/Users/sergidb/Desktop/Borrar/myStackApp/src/app/app.module.ts and 
TestPageModule in 
/Users/sergidb/Desktop/Borrar/myStackApp/src/pages/test/test.module.ts.
```

### Steps to reproduce

1. Create a new Ionic App `ionic start myStackApp tabs`
2. Go to app folder `cd myStackApp`
3. Test app in browser `ionic serve` => App works ok
4. Compile a --prod build `ionic cordova build android --release --prod` => No errors
5. Generate a new page `ionic g page Test`
6. Edit app.module.ts
7. Edit home.ts
8. Edit home.html
9. Test app in browser `ionic serve` => App works ok
10. Compile a --prod build `ionic cordova build android --release --prod` => Ooooops!

The error appears in the console.

### Files after edit:

#### app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

import { AboutPage } from '../pages/about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';
import { TestPage } from '../pages/test/test';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage,
    TestPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage,
    TestPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

#### home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TestPage } from '../test/test';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  goToTest(){
      this.navCtrl.push(TestPage);
  }

}
```

#### home.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h2>Welcome to Ionic!</h2>
  <p>
    This starter project comes with simple tabs-based layout for apps
    that are going to primarily use a Tabbed UI.
  </p>
  <p>
    Take a look at the <code>src/pages/</code> directory to add or change tabs,
    update any existing page or create new pages.
  </p>

    <button ion-button (click)="goToTest()">Go!</button>

</ion-content>
```

### My questions:

- What am I doing wrong?
- Am i not understanding something?

Thanks in advance!

## Edit

#### test.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

/**
 * Generated class for the TestPage page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-test',
  templateUrl: 'test.html',
})
export class TestPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad TestPage');
  }

}
```

#### test.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TestPage } from './test';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TestPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(TestPage),
  ],
  exports: [
    TestPage
  ]
})
export class TestPageModule {}
```

Comment: Do your other pages have @IonicPage at the top and independent .modules.ts files

Comment: @IzzoObella yes, `ionic g page PageName` generates 4 files: .html, .ts, .scss and .module.ts

Comment: @IzzoObella I edited the post adding the test.ts and test.module.ts files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i had the same error when building for production and i fixed it by getting rid of all the different components/pages `.module.ts` then removed the `@IonicPage()` from all my components. For example, **test.ts** would become:-

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

/**
 * Generated class for the TestPage page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'page-test',
  templateUrl: 'test.html',
})
export class TestPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad TestPage');
  }

}
```

Then delete `test.module.ts`. Seems the current ionic-cli build for release & production doesn't support multi-moduling(Child modules).

So i've been researching lazy-loading in ionic 3,so i finally found another better way to use @IonicPage and build production. This is my ionic version info.

```
global packages:

    @ionic/cli-utils : 1.4.0
    Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1 
    Ionic CLI        : 3.4.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts              : https://registry.npmjs.org/@ionic/app-scripts/-/app-scripts-1.3.7.tgz
    @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.0
    @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.1
    Cordova Platforms               : android 6.2.3
    Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic-angular/-/ionic-angular-3.2.1.tgz

System:

    Node       : v7.4.0
    OS         : Linux 4.6
    Xcode      : not installed
    ios-deploy : not installed
    ios-sim    : not installed
    npm        : 5.0.0
```

So in your function `goToTestPage() above, you would change the`this.navParams.push(TestPage)`to`this.navParams.push('TestPage');` with the page as a string. This safely implements lazy-loading. For more on lazy loading ion ionic 3 you can reference this [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7j-P-ElAqe8).